# passing top pointer of stack as argument

Tags: c, pointers, data-structures

My problem is based on pointers, I want to know how can i pass top of stack in function printStack() so that i can access all nodes of stack.I am storing elements in array and same time pushing into stack.

here in this code when i execute it does not print anything.

here my code

```
#include<stdio.h>

struct stack
{
    int data;
    struct stack *next;
};
typedef struct stack s;
s *top=NULL,*neu;

//push data into stack
void push(int data)
{
    neu = (s *)malloc(sizeof(s));
    neu->data= data;
    neu->next = NULL;

   if(!top)
   {
       neu=top;
   }
   else
   {
       neu->next = top;
       top = neu;
   }
}

//pop data and move top to top->next
void pop()
{
    s *temp = top;
    top = top->next;
    free(top);
}

//print data present in stack
void printStack(s *top)
{

   while(top)
   {
        printf("%d ",top->data);
        pop();
    }
}

int main()
{
    int i=0,A[3],d;
    for(i=0;i<3;i++)
    {
        scanf("%d",&A[i]);
        push(A[i]);
    }
    printStack(top);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: unless your edits fix typos you originally had in your code (why copy and paste is preferred), you should not edit your code to fix it based on what answers have been given. This confuses future readers of this question by changing the context in which the answer was given. If one of the answers fixed your problem, leave your code as-is and accept that answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So there are 3 problems:-

- You are freeing `top` rather than `temp` in `pop()`.
- You are changing to the local variable passed in `printStack`.

Simply call this `printSack();` having function signature `void printStack()`.

- Also when creating the nodes

  ```
  if(!top)
  {
     neu=top;
     ^^^^
  }
  ```

This will be `top=neu;`

---

#### Some things that you should learn to do:-

- Use debugger. Learn how to use it.
- Don't cast the return value of `malloc`.
- Check the return value of `malloc` and `scanf`.
- You have used too many global variables - *code that involves lots of global variables are tend to be difficult to debug*. You could easily avoid it here.

For example:-

```
if( scanf("%d",&A[i])!= 1){
   fprintf(stderr,"Error in input");
   exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

In case of `malloc`

```
neu = malloc(sizeof(s));
if(neu == NULL ){
   perror("Malloc failed");
   exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

---

The main thing is - your code is doing nothing basically. It is even useless to create those methods which are so closely couped with each other with data. We use functions so that code becomes modular and each of the function should be reusable.( Atleast to some extent). Here you have missed that part.

Answer (score 1):

You have a simple error here:

```
void pop()
{
    s *temp = top;
    top = top->next;
    free(top);
}
```

Rather than freeing Top, you likely meant to `free(temp);`

Additionally, consider developing good habits early.  Don't cast the return of `malloc()` in C.  Also, don't assume that `malloc()` worked; check to see if it returns something other than NULL.

Comment: thanks @David Hoelzer, i was looking for some problem in my pointers this whole time.

Comment: Any list of good habits should include not using the *expletive filtered* globals as the top item.

Comment: @n.m. I don't disagree (at all) but I find it's not great to overwhelm people with too much at once.